# Make a Auto slide show

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create slide show I loaded the picture in picture box 2 through form load and in the timer options left him enabled here is my code  and for some reason it is not changing pictures I also tried to do it with out loading a picture through form load same thing not changing just blank

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim max As Integer = 10000
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim rand As Integer = rnd.Next(10, max + 1)
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim number(max - 1) As Integer
    For i = 0 To max - 1
        If number(i) = rand Then
            rand = rnd.Next(1, max + 1)
            i = -1
        ElseIf number(i) = 0 Then
            number(i) = rand
            rand = rnd.Next(1, max + 1)
            If i = max - 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            i = -1
        End If
    Next
    Timer1.Interval = number(i)
    i += 1
    ChangeImage()
End Sub
Private Sub ChangeImage()
    Static Dim iImage1 As Integer
    Select Case iImage1
        Case 0
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image2
            iImage1 += 1
        Case 1
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Classic_Burger_SpendWithPennies__2
            iImage1 += 1
        Case 2
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image4
            iImage1 += 1
        Case 3
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image5
            iImage1 += 1
        Case 4
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Classic_Burger_SpendWithPennies__2
            iImage1 += 1
    End Select
```

Comment: Two other things.  Change `Dim rnd As New Random` to `Static rnd As New Random`.  You only want ONE instance of Random to be REUSED over and over.  The way you have it, a different Random instance is created with every Tick() event.  Instead of repeating `iImage1 += 1` in each Case statement, just put it at the bottom after the `End Select` line.

Comment: now I have progress it is changing just first picture PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image2 and rest of them not

Comment: The only way to exit your loop is when `i` is at `max - 1` (your `If` to exit is pointless since that already occurs).  After the loop exits, you add 1 to `i`...therefore `i` will only ever be 10,000 when the loop exits.  Even if you make the suggested changes by "UserNam3" (which is a good suggestion) to pass in the `i` value to ChangeImage(), where in your `Select Case` statement is there a `Case 10000`?  Explain, only using words,  what you actually want to happen in the Tick() event.

Comment: What is the code in that tick event trying to achieve?

Comment: I  want just to change a picture every 10 seconds in picture box2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want just to change a picture every 10 seconds in picture box2

Make sure the Interval property of your Timer is set to 10,000.

Then use code like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static rnd As New Random
    Dim i As Integer = rnd.Next(5) ' 0 to 4 inclusive
    Select Case i
        Case 0
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image2

        Case 1
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Classic_Burger_SpendWithPennies__2

        Case 2
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image4

        Case 3
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Image5

        Case 4
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Classic_Burger_SpendWithPennies__2

    End Select
End Sub
```

But I suspect there is more to this story.  What were you trying to do with the Interval?

Comment: Glad that helped.  Why are Case 1 and Case 4  exactly the same?  Is that a typo?...or is that factoring in some kind of probability?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you dont pass the parameter.
In your sub ChangeImage, you set a **new** variable.

Change like this :

```
ChangeImage(i)
End Sub

 Private Sub ChangeImage(iImage1)

    Select Case iImage1
```

Comment: still same issue not changing the picture in PictureBox2

Comment: I was talking about how to apply the value of i to the ChangeImage sub.
It remains to be seen how you define this value.